# To get list of added removed and modified files in directory using python script

Tags: python, linux, networking, directory, md5sum

I  wrote a Python script that will get the md5sum of all files in a directory(linux)
now i want to get list of added and removed and modified files from that directory

```
from commands import getoutput
import os
import hashlib
from os import walk
files = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk('/home/omkarp/testmd'):
    for file in filenames:
        files.append(os.path.join(dirpath,file))

md5_cmd = "md5sum %s"
md5sum = []
for f in files:
    md5sum.append(getoutput(md5_cmd % (f)))
#print md5sum
dict_md = {}
for d in md5sum:
    var = d.split(" ")
    dict_md[var[2]] = var[0]
print dict_md
fp = open("/home/omkarp/md5sum.txt", 'w')
#for md5 in md5sum:
    #fp.write(md5 + "\n")
fp.write(str(dict_md))
fp.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
import ast

fp = open("md5sum.txt", 'r')
contents = fp.read()

dictionary = ast.literal_eval(contents) # evaluates file content as a dictionnary

for key, value in dict_md.items():
    try:
        sum = dictionary[key]
    except KeyError: # If the key is not in the dictionnary
        print "New file"
    if sum!=value: # If the md5sum is different
        print "File modified"
```